# suffix notation in gnuplot kilo mega mili micro nano pico

Tags: string, format, gnuplot, scientific-notation

I know how to use suffix notation in gnuplot axis :

```
set ytics format "%.1s%c"
```

howver that is not taken into account in sprintf ...

> ```
> gnuplot> pr sprintf("%s", 2e+3)
>      f_sprintf: attempt to print numeric value with string format
> ```

So I made my own function :

```
suffixNotation(x)=sprintf("%g%s",\
(x>=1e+9&&x<1e+12 ) ? x*1e-9 :\
(x>=1e+6&&x<1e+9 ) ? x*1e-6 :\
(x>=1e+3&&x<1e+6 ) ? x*1e-3 :\
(x>=1e-3&&x<1    ) ? x*1e+3 :\
(x>=1e-6&&x<1e-3 ) ? x*1e+6 :\
(x>=1e-9&&x<1e-6 ) ? x*1e+9 :\
(x>=1e-12&&x<1e-9) ? x*1e+12 : x\
,\
(x>=1e+6&&x<1e+12 ) ? "G" :\
(x>=1e+6&&x<1e+9 ) ? "M" :\
(x>=1e+3&&x<1e+6 ) ? "k" :\
(x>=1e-3&&x<1    ) ? "u" :\
(x>=1e-6&&x<1e-3 ) ? "n" :\
(x>=1e-9&&x<1e-6 ) ? "p" :\
(x>=1e-12&&x<1e-9) ? "f" : ""\
)

# gnuplot> i=4.321e-13 ; while (i<10e6) { pr suffixNotation(i); i=i*10;}
# 4.321e-13 4.321f 43.21f 432.1f 4.321p 43.21p 432.1p 4.321n 43.21n 432.1n 4.321u 43.21u 432.1u 4.321 43.21 432.1 4.321k 43.21k 432.1k 4.321G
```

Question 1 ? Does anyone knows if this function already exist in gnuplot ?

Question 2 ? Is it planned by gnuplot developer to add it in sprintf ?

Question 3 ? How do we handle 'package' in gnuplot like load("$GNUPLOTPATH/suffixNotation.gp"), I mean properly.

Comment: I added an answer only to your questions 1 and 2. About the 'package' I would suggest you to ask a new question, because it has nothing to do with the rest. Also, you should be more clear about what you understand with "properly".

Comment: Thanks Christoph, do you know by any chance the opposite function ? print "2k"+0 #==> 2.0 which is wrong. I would have called this function string2float("2.3k") ==> 2.3e+3. Some software can even interpret 2.3n+3p, which is great. I hope gnuplot could do that.

Comment: No, there is no function to parse strings in gnuplot. Here is an own implementation: `scan_scival(s) = s[:strlen(s)]*(strstrt("munpaz", s[strlen(s):]) > 0 ? 10**(-3.0*strstrt("munpaz", s[strlen(s):])) : (strstrt("kMGTP", s[strlen(s):])
 > 0 ? 10**(3.0*strstrt("kMGTP", s[strlen(s):])) : 0))`. This contain some duplications, but is cleaner since gnuplot functions don't have a local scope and any variables defined inside the function would be visible after calling the function. `print scan_scival("3.44e4k")` gives `34400000.0`.

Answer (score 3):

Gnuplot provides its own formatting function `gprintf` which supports all these gnuplot-specific format specifiers

```
print gprintf('%.1s%c', 2e+3)
```

prints

```
2.0k
```

Quoting the official documentation:

> The string function `gprintf("format", x)` uses gnuplot's own format specifiers, as do the gnuplot commands **set format**, **set timestamp**, and others.  These format specifiers are not the same as those used by the
>   standard  C-language  routine `sprintf()`. `gprintf()`  accepts  only  a  single  variable  to  be  formatted.